# A/B Testing - Repeated Sampling

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, ab-test

I am doing an internship in a marketing firm where they do a lot of A/B testing.

My question/concern was that it seems that given a population, they only "split" it into an A and B group a single time and then carry out their measurements. Ideally, to reduce variance and have confidence in the results, shouldn't they do something like bootstrapping, or repeated sampling of A and B groups?

Comment: Do you mean randomize each time you see a user/cookie begin a new session?

Comment: No, I mean given a list of 100 customers, they randomly put say 50% in group A and 50% in group B, and perform the needed calculations. However, just doing one 50-50 random split may yield completely different results than a different 50-50 random split, so I am just curious why that is not taken into account when people talk about a/b testing.

Comment: That's precisely the uncertainty that the confidence interval (or the standard error) for the difference is meant to capture.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Unfortunately, most of the companies in practice just take the "one number" approach, they don't talk about confidence intervals or standard errors, it is frustrating!

Comment: The uncharitable interpretation is that the company is being dishonest, and that the experiment is just cargo cult nonsense. The charitable one is that they made sure the lift was significant, statistically and economically, before making their recommendation to the client, but don't want to explain CIs and just distill the evidence to a single number. The details might all be buried in an appendix somewhere. We really don't have enough information here to tell the difference.

Comment: You can read more about marketing measurement done right in [this nice article](https://thecorrespondent.com/100/the-new-dot-com-bubble-is-here-its-called-online-advertising/13228924500-22d5fd24). At the very least, this internship will reveal if this company is the kind of place where you might want to work.